# How to forbid no attribute given

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

I've written an XSD about managing movies elements. My problem is that I don't want the given XML file to be validated if he gives no attribute genre i.e `<genre />`: this statement shouldn't be validated.

I tried `<xs:assert>` to eliminate that situation but it doesn't validate.
In brief: I want my xsd to validate movies with exactly one genre.

```
<xs:element name="genre">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="thriller" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
        <xs:attribute name="horror" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
        <xs:attribute name="scifi" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
        <xs:attribute name="romance" type="xs:string" use="optional" />                             
        <xs:attribute name="literature" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give examples of the xml you are validating:    The given xsd enforces a genre element, with a different attribute for each genre ( eg; <genre horror="" romance="">),  which quite frankly is a very poor design for xml structure.

Comment: <title>string</title>
      <authors>string</authors>
      <year_of_publication>-2989</year_of_publication>
      <genre thriller="string" />
      <edition>string</edition>

Answer (score 0):

If you're using xsd 1.1, you can use xs:key to enforce a constraint like so:

```
<xs:element name="movie">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="authors" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="year_of_publication" type="xs:short"/>
            <xs:element name="genre" >
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="romance" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="thriller" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="horror" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="scifi" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="literature" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
                </xs:complexType>
                <xs:key name="OnlyOneGenreAttributePresent">
                    <xs:selector xpath="." />
                    <xs:field xpath="@romance | @thriller | @romance | @scifi | @literature " />
                </xs:key>                   
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="edition" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But if you can, it is far better to alter XML structure to something that is more "correct".  For example,instead of:

```
<genre scifi="string" />
```

use:

```
<genre>scifi<genre>
```

It will simplify the xsd and allow for a xsd that is xsd 1.0 compliant:

```
<xs:simpleType name="T_genres">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="thriller"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="horror"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="romance"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="scifi"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="literature"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="movie">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="authors" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="year_of_publication" type="xs:short"/>
                <xs:element name="genre"  type="T_genres" />
                <xs:element name="edition" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Creating a global <xs:simpleType> allows for easier maintenance. The xs:restriction/xs:enumeration limits to single value and has the added benefit of enabling some intellisense in many xml editors.